# Existing templates - Minecraft server info page

Tags: html, minecraft

**Background:** Recently i've created a game server for Minecraft. Now i would like to create webpage with some info and in future with video blog with game recordings.

**Question:** Are somewhere already done, ready to reuse, HTML 5 (<video>, maybe canvas in future) templates for such pages?

As example [Fansite Kit for Starcraft 2](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/media/downloads/) (Downloads filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjin.com is a CMS that will allow you to sign up and has related themes. If you're running Bukkit or any of its forks there's a plugin so Enjin can query your server.

If you have a little coding experience I would suggest starting off with bootstrap and use the JSONAPI plugin to query your server.